# How to configure primefaces with existing JSF application?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, primefaces

I am beginner for JSF, when I am configuring Primefaces on Eclipse, then I am getting exceptions. I have done following things to add the primefaces to my existing JSF application.

1. Added jar file `primefaces-3.5.jar` to the library
2. Then I have modified my xhtml page, the content of xhtml page is as follows

   `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"`

Then it's showing the error

```
NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB 
in: 
org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.validation.internal.facelet.messages
```

What can be done here to resolve this problem?

Eclipse details are

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Kepler Release
Build id: 20130614-0229
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"` to `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"`

It is missing the following tag lib in your page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    ...
</html>
```

Make sure to set put the jar files in `WEB-INF` folder

```
+ WEB-INF
    - primefaces-3.5-XXX.jar
    - jsf-api_2.1_spec-xx.jar -> When your server already exist as a server module, your don't need to put.
```

Comment: You forgot to **explain** the problem, so here it is: the taglib URI `http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui` is specific to PrimeFaces 2.x, however the OP is trying to use PrimeFaces 3.x which has a different taglib URI, `http://primefaces.org/ui`. Hence this error. After all, OP should be reading PrimeFaces 3.x documentation and tutorials instead of 2.x ones.

Comment: thz, yes. URI is changed.